# Show that the center $Z(G)$ forms a subgroup of $G$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to prove that the center of a group is a subgroup, and so far I've managed to prove that $Z(G)$ is not empty and closure. I've also come up with a proof that the inverse element exists however I'm not sure if it's correct:

Let $r\in Z(G)$. Then, it follows that $r\in G$ and hence there exists $r^{-1}\in G$ such that

$rr^{-1}=r^{-1}r=e$(the identity element)

Let $g\in G$, then from:

$\begin{aligned} 
gr&=rg \qquad \qquad /\cdot r^{-1}\\
r^{-1}\cdot/\qquad \qquad g&=rgr^{-1}\\ 
r^{-1}g&=gr^{-1}\implies r^{-1}\in Z(G) 
\end{aligned}$

Comment: The proof for the inverse is correct.

Comment: Compare your solution with the [duplicates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1296431/the-center-of-a-group-g-is-a-subgroup-of-g/1296440).